# Best tool to create a full screen slide show from the web

Tags: javascript, flash, image, slideshow

I need to create a slide show of some images that can go full screen so it can be displayed via S-Video out.

The software is delivered via the web so a web-based option is needed.

The list of images is dynamic, and I would like to show them in order. The list of photos can change while the slideshow is running, and I would like to add the new photos to the slideshow.

I see two options:

1. Build it using JavaScript and then use a browser plugin to go full screen. I have a prototype of this, however it displays photos in random order.
2. Build it using Flash. I know nothing about Flash so I am looking for slideshows that can go full screen.

What would be best? Are there any good, customizable Flash slideshows?

Comment: It sounds like you have almost what you need in JavaScript. You just need to change from random order to a fixed order. Since you know nothing about Flash, why not just fix the JavaScript prototype you have?

Comment: Yeah, I am leaning towards that, but if there's a kick-ass Flash slideshow I can configure I would be apt to use that instead. The downside to the JS version is figuring out how to kill the browser chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those interested, I ended up making an Adobe AIR application using HTML and JavaScript. Adobe AIR can go full screen and I was able to leverage the knowledge of HTML and JavaScript I already have. It has worked out pretty well, though there was a rather steep learning curve for the native AIR classes and how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Flash, [SlideShowPro](http://slideshowpro.net/) is a good option that you may recognize from sites like ESPN.

Comment: Agree. But I think you can not add images on the fly without reloading the component.

Answer (score 0):

when you say "fullscreen", do you mean taking up ENTIRE screen? if so, javascript is not a tool to use, it must live inside the browser, so you will always have some chrome visible from the browser.

flash can do full screen, on the other hand.

Comment: Right. I would like to hide the browser chrome. If going the JavaScript route I'm hoping to find a kiosk plugin that can hide the browser chrome, so it really can be full screen.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers allow you to go full screen (even hiding the chrome) with the F11 key (requires user input). Then it's just a matter of scaling the image in javascript to the size of the viewport. If it doesn't exists, it could be written easily enough probably from a preexisting gallery script.

Also, [this answer may be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228377/could-a-website-force-the-browser-to-go-into-fullscreen-mode)

Hope that helps.